# cross browser keypress -scroll to top

Tags: jquery, scroll, keypress, scrolltop

I found this code a while back for use with an html element

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

But how do I trigger this when the 't' key is pressed? For all major browsers?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 84){
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
});
```